# Calculating the eigenvector centrality of a portfolio described by a minimum spanning tree

Tags: asset-allocation, graphs, eigenvalue

I am working with the eigenvector centrality of a minimum spanning tree, which can be calculated as:

`v(i) = lambda^-1 * sum[Omega(i,j)*v(j)]`

where:

- `v(i)` is the eigenvector centrality of the node i-th
- `Omega` is an adjacency matrix (square)
- `lambda` is the biggest eigenvalue of the Omega matrix
- `v(j)` is the eigenvector centrality of each j-th neighbor node

Let's assume that I want to calculate the eigenvector centrality of a portfolio, i.e. I want to weight each i-th eigenvector centrality v(i) by means of a weighting vector `w`. How can I calculate the weighted centrality of n nodes?

Thank you for your help.

Comment: which article gives the formula that you wrote

Comment: A network approach to portfolio selection; Gustavo Peralta, Abalfazl Zareei (Nov 2014). The formula can be expressed in other ways, if you have another in mind I am flexible.

Comment: Do they not show how to make `w` a function of `v(i)`? Why then is their title portfolio selection

Comment: In their asset allocation they do not solve any optimization problem, they indirectly use eigenvector centrality to build portfolios. Nevertheless, I am not trying to replicate this work, rather build something new, i.e. I want to calculate the eigenvalue centrality of a portfolio and then use it in the optimization.